# Need function that mirrors image coordinates outside of boundaries

Tags: image-processing, opencl

I am performing an NxN image convolution on an image of dimensions
w and h, where N is much smaller than w or h.  Given a coordinate alpha, I would like to calculate a new coordinate safe_alpha that is guaranteed to lie in the bounds. Coordinates outside of the boundary should be mirrored.

i.e., if

```
 alpha = (w-1) +2;
```

then

```
safe_alpha = (w-1) -2;
```

This will be running on a GPU, so I would prefer to avoid conditionals in the calculation.

Mirroring on only the outer boundary is simple:

```
safe_alpha = -| (w-1) - alpha| + alpha;
```

But I need to mirror on both.

Edit:

Here is something that seems to work, but I am not sure if it is the fastest:

```
 safe_alpha = |alpha| + (alpha/(w-1)) * (alpha - (w-1));
```

Comment: "This will be running on a GPU, so I would prefer to avoid conditionals in the calculation."  That could be a misguided requirement.  GPUs have the ability to predicate execution and minimize the cost of conditionals, especially short-scope ones like you are discussing.  Replacing trivial predicated conditionals with sequences of what is likely to be integer arithmetic that may put pressure on integer units may not be optimal.  If you want fast code, you should choose whichever algorithm is fastest. I would much rather have simple conditionals if I can avoid integer division, for example.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. So you are saying  (alpha > w-1) ? alpha - 2(alpha - (w-1)) : alpha would be better, for the right hand boundary?

Comment: By the way, I do have this working with OpenCL images, which have built in mirroring, but I am looking into using OpenCL buffers with the hopes of speeding things up a bit.

Comment: If the alternative is something that uses integer devision, I'll bet it would be better.  But what I'm saying is benchmark it, or disassemble the code and do some analysis based on the actual machine instructions.  Doing unnatural things to avoid conditionals is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Have you considered using texture memory with `wrap` address mode?

Comment: I have some kernels doing weird things on image borders, and usually the performance hit is not in those conditional. Is good if you can cleverly get rid of them, but if you can't, then don't spend too much time on them (they will only slow down the edge processing, since for the center all the WI will take one branch).

Comment: Thanks everyone for their comments. Now I see that branches would only affect edges, so not that serious (I am working with 4K images).  @JackOLantern I am using the equivalent of wrap address mode in OpenCL using OpenCL images, but I am thinking of refactoring back to OpenCL buffers, because they are more flexible.  As long as I can get coalesced memory reads, I think I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know openCL details, but you can avoid edge data mirroring using appropriate convolution window at the edges: convolution window values will double picture edge values. You will need N/2 array of convolution windows (once simply derived from you original N*N window) for every 4 edge and a bit more for corners, but no conditionals and no devisions at all.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
size_t inline mirror_if_out_of_bounds(                                           
    const int x,                                                                 
    const int nx                                                                 
)                                                                                
{                                                                                
  const int r = abs(x%(2*nx));                                                   
  // avoid branching                                                 
  return select((size_t)(2*nx-r-1),(size_t)(r),(size_t)(r<nx));                    
}
```

In your case you don't need the modulus, because you know you are always outside the bounds by less than nx or inside the bounds.

And your solution, if it would work as it should, would be about as fast, just the division would make it a little slower. But I don't think it does, because the coordinate is quadratic in your equation.